# Download Shiny Server on AWS R Server (Linux)

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way to download the shiny server package onto an AWS R Server run on Linux?

The main issue is that AWS's R Server doesn't show anything but R studio so i can not find a way to access terminal to administer the download

Comment: would this help?

http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-rstudio-shiny-server-on-aws/

Comment: You'll need to be able to login to the server via SSH (as in the link @PorkChop provided).

Comment: @PorkChop yes that does.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcoG. Please complete the question and answer it yourself so other users would have a reference